# Erroneous citatations

Tags: search, citation, reissue

In reference to the patent: [US26919](https://www.google.com/patents/US26919)

A number of non-firearm patents cite this patent but they actually refer to the reissue patent R26919 in the text. This is probably a common problem when the numbers overlap. (https://www.google.com/patents/USRE26919)

Comment: This is a community-run website to ask about the patent process or to help find Prior Art on US Patents or Applications. Unfortunately, we we do not actually host these patents nor do we have a direct channel to Google Patents to correct these errors. You will need to contact Google directly to issue these corrections. See the duplicate post linked in the close notice.